# Django: File Upload - Attach a file to a specific job id in task manager app

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am writing a basic task manager app in django. I want to add an additional `FileField` to to my model which will allow users to upload a file and link it to the task. For example the user may write a report as part of a task/job. Then other users could click a hyperlink on a webpage and view the linked_file(s) which are associated with the task. However I am lost on how to do this.

Here is my models.py

```
Class Item(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tag = models.CharField('Tag', max_length=10, default='')
    name = models.CharField('Brief summary of job', max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description of job')

    # Priority
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Low'),
        ('2', 'Intermediate'),
        ('3', 'High'),
        )
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                                choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,
                                default='1')

    # Job Difficulty
    DIFFICULTY_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Easy'),
        ('2', 'Intermediate'),
        ('3', 'Hard'),
        )

    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                                choices=DIFFICULTY_CHOICES,
                                default='1')

    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # Get all users
    users = User.objects.all()
    USER_LIST = [(str(u),str(u)) for u in users]
    job_for = models.CharField('FAO',max_length=30,
                    choices=USER_LIST)

    # Deadline
    deadline = models.DateTimeField('Deadline')

    # Update field
    update = models.TextField('Job Updates', blank=True,default='')
    # Notes - Add any useful points that cropped up during job
    notes = models.TextField('Notes', blank=True, default='')

    # File
    linked_file = models.FileField(upload_to='linked_files/', null=True)
```

Section of `forms.py`

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    linked_file = forms.FileField(
        label='select a file',
        help_text = 'link document to job'
        )
```

and my upload function in `views.py`

```
# Upload Document. Attach to item
def upload(request, item_id):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
#        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newFile = Item(file = request.FILES['linked_file'])
            newFile.save()

            # Redirect to the index after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('index'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form    

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'nc_jobs/upload.html',
        {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

My app.url

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from nc_jobs import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
              # eg /nc_jobs/
#             url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
              url(r'^$', views.joblist_filter , name='index'),
              # eg /nc_jobs/done         
              url(r'^done/$', views.DoneView.as_view(), name='done'),
              url(r'^not_done/$', views.NotDoneView.as_view(), name='not_done'),         
              # eg /nc_jobs/add/
              url(r'^add/$', login_required(views.AddItem.as_view()), name='add_item'),         
              #eg /nc_jobs/5
              url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.UpdateItem.as_view()), name='update_item'),
              #eg /nc_jobs/5/upload
              url(r'^(?P<item_id>\d+)/upload/$', 'nc_jobs.views.upload', name='upload'),
              )
```

And upload.html template

```
{% extends "nc_jobs/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
            <li><a href="/nc_jobs/">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="/nc_jobs/done/">Done</a></li>
            <li><a href="/nc_jobs/not_done/">Not Done</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href=>Upload File</a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block mainblock %}
        <form action="{% url 'upload' item.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.linked_file.label_tag }} {{ form.linked_file.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.linked_file.errors }}
                {{ form.linked_file }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
{%endblock mainblock %}
```

When I go to a url such as `http://localhost:8000/nc_jobs/4/upload/` I am getting hit with an error message

NoReverseMatch at /nc_jobs/4/upload/

`Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['nc_jobs/(?P<item_id>\\d+)/upload/$']`

How do I get around this? Also am I on the write track to uploading a file and linking it to my task item?

Comment: In your views, shouldn't it be `newFile = Item(linked_file=request.FILES['linked_file])`. No?

Comment: @xyres not sure I have changed to this but still the same reversematch error

Answer (score 1):

Your view for 'upload' is not sending any context variable named 'item', so when you try to open the page, `item.id` is empty and it fails because of this.

`<form action="{% url 'upload' item.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Note that the argument in the reversematch error is empty. Also I would recommend going through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/) for File Uploading. I'm not sure whether DocumentForm is a ModelForm but you'll need that or a file upload handler to properly upload your file.  They have a decent enough example there.